# Firefox Browser Extensions not loading: Selenium with Python 2.7

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Using Firefox 54, Python 2.7 and Selenium 3.8.1 I'm trying to load some extensions using a Firefox Profile but Selenium fails to load them. The browser, however, does load with this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def setup_firefox_profile():

    firefox_custom_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(
    r'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\1hmz9w1k.GenericFootprintHardened2')

    firefox_custom_profile.add_extension(r'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\1hmz9w1k.GenericFootprintHardened2\extensions\bestproxyswitcher@bestproxyswitcher.com.xpi')
    # C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile folder>

    # Adblock, Best Proxy Switcher, //BetterPrivacy, Clear Flash Cookies, Canvas Fingerprint Blocker, Cookie Quick Manager, Disable WebRTC, Ghostery, Privacy Badger,

    firefox_custom_profile.set_preference("extensions.bestproxyswitcher.currentVersion", "5.4.2")
    firefox_settings = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_custom_profile)
    return firefox_settings

driver = setup_firefox_profile()

driver.get('http://duckduckgo.com')
```

Attempting to load the profile with a manual session I am able to see the extensions load.

It appears the profile does not load correctly. I found instructions to go to "about:support" and then "Open Folder" under the Profile Folder heading. The directory did not match the profile in name or path ("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpp4lzxe")

Can anyone see why the profile is not being loaded?

Is the code for loading the extensions also wrong?

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution to this?

Comment: Also, could you suggest something to me? In the documentation it says that geckodriver needs python 3, would it run with 2.7 as well?

Comment: @NewGuy, It's been a long time, I don't think I found a solution, sorry